# Knockout required validated errors with onlyIf- Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: knockout.js

I am using onlyIf validator within Required validator in my viewModel. My requirement is that identifierId should only be required if I select employee id radio button.
I am getting error in binding as-
Cannot read property 'selectedOptionValue' of undefined.

And here is js-

```
     var viewModelId = {
     selectedOptionValue: ko.observable(),

     identifierId: ko.observable().extend({
               required: { message: requiredIdentifierId, onlyIf: function () { return (viewModelId.selectedOptionValue() === 'employeeid'); } },
               minLength: { params: 2, message: invalidLengthId },
               maxLength: 15,
               pattern: {
                  params: patterns.identifier,
                  message: invalidId
      }
});
```

Here is my HTML-

```
  <input type="radio" value="employeeid" name="identifier" data-bind="checked: selectedOptionValue"/>       <label>employee id</label>
          <div data-bind="visible: selectedOptionValue() == 'employeeid'">
           <input class="intro-line id-text" data-bind="value: identifierId" />
           </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the validation is triggered *immediately* after you define it, even before the `viewModelId` object is complete.

One way to avoid this is to extend the observable after you construct the object it belongs to:

```
var viewModelId = {
    selectedOptionValue: ko.observable(),
    identifierId: ko.observable()
};

viewModelId.identifierId.extend({
    required: {
        message: requiredIdentifierId,
        onlyIf: function () {
            return viewModelId.selectedOptionValue() === 'employeeid';
        }
    },
    minLength: {
        params: 2,
        message: invalidLengthId
    },
    maxLength: 15,
    pattern: {
        params: patterns.identifier,
        message: invalidId
    }
});
```